# I'm a bit confused what benefit .each() has

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this is a novice question, but I don't understand what benefit `.each()` has over a normal `$()` selector. The `$()` selects all instances of what the selector is and applies what ever is applied to the selector to all its matching instances. My immediate reaction is: well `.each()` allows for more complex things, but you can method chain with jquery, so I can do more complex things with the normal selector also. For example, if I have 5 `p` elements and I write:

```
 $("p").css("color","blue");//this would be applied to all five p elements

 $("p").each(function(){$(this).css("color","blue")});//this does the
                                                      //same thing
```

I'm sure there is a use for `.each()`, I'm just currently having trouble seeing it, the normal selector seems to loop through everything already. Could someone give me example for why I would want to use `.each()`?

Comment: It will be useful when you need to set different color for each element.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example that sets the color of each element based on it's `data-color` attribute.

```js
$("p").each(function(){$(this).css("color", $(this).data("color"))});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-color="red">Red</p>
<p data-color="green">Green</p>
<p data-color="blue">Blue</p>
```

Basically, `$.each()` will let you invoke a function that has access to the element in question. This in turn allows you to invoke functionality based on some property or attribute of said element.

Comment: dat one-liner tho

Comment: @Miro Personally, I think I'd go for: `$("p").each((i, el) => $(el).css("color", $(el).data("color")));`